# AS3 mouseChildren = false add Event Listeners to children

Tags: actionscript-3, events, mouseevent

I have a drop down in flash with two buttons that drop down. On the object I use add these event listeners:

```
addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, expand);
addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, contract);

public function expand(evt:MouseEvent):void
        {
            if(!expanded)
            {
                TweenMax.to(this.back, 0.15, {height:82, onComplete:function(){
                    music.alpha = 1;
                    music.y = 32;
                    quit.alpha = 1;
                    quit.y = 55;
                }});
                expanded = true;
            }
        }

    public function contract(evt:MouseEvent):void
    {
        if(expanded)
        {
            this.music.alpha = 0;
            this.music.y = 0 - this.height;
            this.quit.alpha = 0;
            this.quit.y = 0 - this.height;
            TweenMax.to(this.back, 0.15, {height:0});
            expanded = false;
        }
    }
```

In order for the menu to work correctly I need to add this code so the children don't interfere with the triggering of the two functions.

```
this.mouseChildren = false;
```

Now I want the two buttons on the drop down to be clickable and trigger different events but since the mouseChildren is set to false it won't listen to events. How can I assign events to the children of my object and not have the expand, contract function interrupted by interaction of those two child elements?

Thanks,
Brennan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can't you just put:

```
this.mouseChildren = true;
```

inside of the onComplete function for your expansion tween

and then:

```
this.mouseChildren = false;
```

inside of the onComplete function for your contraction tween?

This would enable the mouse on those children only when the menu expands.

Comment: That doesn't work. As soon as it sets it to true the Event Listener for contract is triggered.

Comment: Okay it worked as soon as I changed the event listeners to ROLL_OVER and ROLL_OUT! Thanks